# staticfiles and STATIC_URL with virrtualenv - django

Tags: django, static, virtualenv

I'm using virtualenv and I can't get staticfiles to work on my django,

```
# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    '/home/brian/Projects/RaffleFish/static',

)
```

My virtualenv directory is virt_env/virtFish

How do I get my staticfiles to work? do I add the directory structure of virtenv

Answer (score 2):

Inside the individual applications within your Django project you can create a `static` directory and place static files within that directory.  Those files will automatically be handled by the `django.contrib.staticfiles` module which should be in the INSTALLED_APPS tuple in your settings.py file.  These files will be aggregated and served during the development process automatically by the `python manage.py runserver` command.

The trick to this process that you must keep in mind is that when it comes time to deploy to production, or any environment where you aren't serving content with `manage.py` you will have to perform that aggregation yourself.  The `manage.py` command has a command to help with this.  As a part of your deploy you should include the command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

This will collect (aggregate) all the static files from the `static` directories in your apps into a single location defined in `settings.py` by the `STATIC_ROOT` setting.